# Should my questions be long and formatted?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There will be questions that are very simple, **Like This One**, that I think it should not have any pictures, formats, and that the question should be short and straight to the point.

**Should I do that, is it fine, and will it affect most of the user's opinions of my question?**

Comment: See [Ask], which explains what good questions should consist of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users' opinion of your question won't be influenced by fancy formatting or length.  In fact excessive formatting can hurt your question if not done right.  And questions that are too long are usually not well received because they often are difficult to figure out the actual issue.  Likewise short questions tend not to be well received as they usually don't contain all of the key items needed to be answered without guessing.

The quality of the question is really centered on a few very critical points

- Does the question contain all of the necessary information to answer the question.  It needs to contain all of the following when applicable

  - Error messages (or a description of whatever the problem is) - most importantly the name, but for more obscure error messages, you might need more detail
  - MCVE (shortest piece of code that demonstrates the problem).  Too much code is a serious problem.  If you don't know how to shorten your code, then you are not ready to ask for help on Stack Overflow.**
  - The environment you are using is also important.  Make sure you have the appropriate tags and anything else critical that isn't a tag is in the question body.  A couple of great examples are [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).  There are so many different variations of each that just asking about "regex" or "sql" with identifying your language or environment usually make the question unanswerable.  Language versions fit into this as well.  Answering a C# question would be radically different if someone is using C# 2.0 vs 7.0
- Is the post brief and to the point.  Don't add a lot of unnecessary background.  What is your problem?  What issue are you encountering?  How did you try to fix it?
- Are you doing something unusual?  If so why do you have to do it *this way*?  X-Y problems are common downvote magnets because the OP insists the problem **must** be solved in a specific fashion, while doing it another way is infinitely easier.

As Martjin linked, the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be a huge help, as can Jon Skeet's [How to ask the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), which is condensed to [Stack Overflow Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

** - creating a good MCVE can be a difficult task for some.  The shortest way is to start removing code until the problem goes away.  Then add in the last bit of code you remove.  That is *usually* the offending code.

Comment: Also useful is the environment, e.g. "SQL Server 2012" (and tag as such), and any constraints, e.g. "It can't involve a user-defined function and must work in the Southern hemisphere." That helps to reduce the effort spent posting correct answers to the problem as stated, only to find that the user is running old software, lacks privileges or has arbitrary constraints imposed by an outside authority that render the answers inapplicable.

Comment: @HABO good point.  I've incorporated that into the post

Answer (score 6):

Nobody wants to read more than they have to. The longer your question, the more likely nobody is going to read it. [TL;DR](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr). *If* you're going to write something very long out of necessity – and really decide how *necessary* it really is first – you'll need to establish something that pulls the reader in very quickly in the title and first paragraph. Your post is one among thousands posted every day, there's no reason anyone would waste time on it unless it is interesting for some reason.

Ask exactly what you need to ask, no more, no less. Supply enough context for your question to be answerable, no more, no less. Obviously this can be hard to judge, so try reading your own post from the perspective of somebody who is not you. If you pulled a random (competent) stranger from the street, would they understand what you want?

Your post should obviously be *formatted*. Formatted *properly* that is. Formatting does not mean to `randomly` **interject** <kbd>all</kbd> the ***various*** <sub>formatting</sub> MarKUp that <sup>is</sup> available. That just makes your post unreadable. Formatting is to be used properly. Ensure code is formatted properly as code. Quotes are formatted as quotes. Use *italics* or **bold** only to highlight important parts which must stand out for some reason or another. Don't highlight too much; if everything is highlighted, then nothing is. The point of proper formatting is to make it easier for the reader to absorb the information. If you're overusing it, it has the exact opposite effect.

In the end, this all just comes down to good writing. You may want to visit https://writing.stackexchange.com for tips with that.